# Как определить гласный перед -ть в инфинитиве?

Tags: орфография, глаголы, правила

У ребенка проблема с правописанием глаголов, например мурыж(?)ть, се(?)ть, кле(?)ть, кашл(?)ть.
В справочнике Лопатина нашлось правило:
*После шипящих согласных в глаголах с усекаемой основой перед -ть пишется буква **И**, а в глаголах с неусекаемой основой — буквы **А или Е**, напр.: наскучить (ср. наскучу, наскучат), но: вешать (ср. вешает, вешают), ополоуметь (ополоумеют).*

Но остался нераскрытым вопрос: А или Е?? СплетничАть или сплетничЕть? Как определить, какая из них, если не знаешь, как пишется?

Comment: P.S. Не говоря уже о том, что М в слове "ополоуметь" с каких-то пор стал, видимо, шипящим

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**А. Основные правила выбора безударного глагольного суффикса** (это конспект существующих правил)

**1)  Формальные (эмпирические) правила**

**Примечание** (почему приходится пользоваться формальными правилами, основанными на статистике)

Выбор суффикса пред ТЬ – это по сути грамматическая, а не орфографическая задача, так как  суффикс  является **значащей частью слова**.

Однако выбрать глагольный суффикс по значению не всегда возможно ввиду его многозначности: например: ***решать – решить,*** здесь суффикс И противопоставлен суффиксу А по виду и обозначает совершенный вид; ***висеть – повесить***, здесь суффикс И противопоставлен суффиксу Е по переходности и обозначает переходный глагол.

Но в некоторых случаях **грамматическое правило всё-таки применяется,** например: обезлюдеть (неперех.) – обезлюдить (перех.), также нежный – нежничать, суффикс ИЧА. В других же случаях мы пользуемся формальной статистикой или запоминаем слова как исключения.

**Выбор суффиксов А или О после твердых согласных**

Если слышится звук А, то выбирается **суффикс А**, так как суффикс О является всегда ударным (кроме вариантов с приставкой ВЫ):  ***бегать, думать, прятать, резать*** – непроизводные глаголы; ***обед – обедать, ужин – ужинать*** – производные глаголы. **Суффикс О** всегда ударный, исключением являются глаголы с ударной приставкой ВЫ: ***выполоть, выколоть***.

**Выбор суффиксов Я, Е или И после мягких согласных (если слышится звук И)**

**Суффикс Я** пишется, если в основе глагола присутствуют звуки ЭЙ, АЙ, УЙ: ***таять, отчаяться, веять, сеять, надеяться, чуять.***

**Суффикс Е** в безударной позиции пишется в  4-х  глаголах на ЕТЬ, которые как исключение заучиваются при определении  спряжения: ***видеть, обидеть, ненавидеть зависеть.***

**Суффикс И**  пишется  в остальных случаях: 
***строить, бросить, красить, ездить, чистить*** – непроизводные глаголы; ***мороз – морозить, печаль – печалить*** – производные глаголы.

**2) Словарные варианты**

Несколько глаголов являются исключением из этого правила, эти глаголы надо запомнить:  ***клеить, драить*** (хотя ЭЙ и АЙ в основе), ***кланяться,  кашлять*** (нет звуков ЭЙ, АЙ, УЙ).

3) **Парные суффиксы  Е/И и ЕНЕ/ЕНИ  в отыменных переходных и непереходных глаголах**

При образовании глаголов от существительных и прилагательных для переходных глаголов используются  суффиксы И и ЕНИ, а для непереходных  глаголов –  суффиксы Е и ЕНЕ: 
***обессилеть, обезлюдеть, опротиветь, обезденежеть*** (самому) – Е в непереходных глаголах;       ***обессилить, обезлюдить*** (кого-то) –  И в переходных глаголах;
***лёд – леденеть*** (самому) – ЕНЕ в непереходных глаголах;  ***лёд – леденить*** (кого-то) – ЕНИ в переходных глаголах.

**4) Особенности  решения орфограммы  для глагольных суффиксов после шипящих**
   Исключительные правила при выборе суффикса после шипящих связаны с  особенным изменением гласного звука в безударном положении:  все гласные звуки после шипящих (как твёрдых, так и мягких) произносятся как звук, похожий на И/Ы, то есть редукция звука происходит по мягкому варианту, поэтому три гласных  суффикса **А, И, Е** не различаются по произношению.

Основной формой является **суффикс И**, который используется в большинстве случаев: ***увеличить, нянчить, рыбачить,  тревожить, нежиться.***

**Суффикс Е**  встречается в редких случаях, как в рассмотренном выше непереходном глаголе обезденежеть (самому).

**Суффикс А** после шипящих пишется  в единичных случаях, которые следует запомнить: ***ворочать, ворочаться, вешать,  слушать, слышать, кушать.***

Для образования глаголов от существительных и прилагательных используются суффиксы **НИЧА/ИЧА:** ***нежный – нежничать, нервы – нервничать, дело – бездельничать.***

**5) Выбор глагольного суффикса при наличии ударной приставки ВЫ**

Для глаголов с приставкой ВЫ выбор суффикса делается в  **бесприставочных** глаголах:  ***держать – выдержать, стоять – выстоять, смотреть – высмотреть,  ставить – выставить, слушать – выслушать***.

Иногда приставка ВЫ совместно с суффиксом И используется для образования отыменных глаголов от прилагательных: ***прямой – выпрямить, светлый – высветлить.***

В некоторых случаях при выборе глагольного суффикса учитывается **значение вида**:  ***стрелять – выстрелить, ронять – уронить и выронить***,  суффикс Я – несовершенный вид, суффикс И – совершенный вид.  Но:  ***ровнять***  (несовершенный  вид) и  ***выровнять*** (совершенный вид)  –  пишется суффикс Я в виде исключения.

**Б. Ответ на вопрос (по конспекту)**

***Мурыжить*** –  суффикс И как основной вариант **после шипящих**, также подходит для переходного глагола; редкий глагол, желательное проверить по словарю.

***Сеять*** – звуки ЭЙ в основе, ***клеить, кашлять*** – исключения (запомнить).

***Наскучить*** – основной суффикс И после шипящих, вешать – единичный суффикс А (запомнить)

***Ополоуметь*** (самому) – непереходный глагол, суффикс Е.

***Сплетничать*** – суффикс ИЧА.

**Примечание**

В правилах ПАС под ред. Лопатина написание глаголов вида ***таять, веять, чуять*** объясняется не очень удачно. В этих глаголах происходит **встреча гласных (именно это главное)**, и после  А, Е, У пишется суффикс Я а после  О – суффикс И (***строить, беспокоить***). Говорить здесь об усекаемых и неусекаемых основах нет особого смысла (хотя основа в этих глаголах действительно усекаемая).

Comment: Jasmin: _Сеять – основа на  **А**Й_... === **?**

Comment: Имеются в виду звуки ЭЙ, АЙ, УЙ, а не буквы.

Comment: Jasmin: _Имеются в виду звуки ЭЙ, АЙ, УЙ, а не буквы_. === О, господи! И где же в слове "сеять" находятся звуки АЙ?

Comment: А где же вежливость и дружелюбие? Пожалуйста, прочитайте правила поведения на сайте.

Comment: Jasmin: _А где же вежливость и дружелюбие?_ === В первом моём комментарии.

Comment: Интересно, как бы выглядел ваш третий комментарий.

Comment: >> У ребенка проблема с правописанием глаголов... @Jasmin, у РЕБЕНКА проблема! А вы что предлагаете? Трактат?

Comment: Это Лопатин ребенка совсем запутал со своей усекаемой основой, а я предлагаю простую инструкцию пользователя  вида 7+  Слышишь звук А и пиши букву А - куда уж проще?

Comment: Jasmin: _Интересно, как бы выглядел ваш третий комментарий_.  === Третий мой комментарий -- по поводу Вашей последней правки, где Вы написали: _"В правилах ПАС под ред. Лопатина написание глаголов вида таять, веять, чуять объясняется не очень удачно. В этих глаголах происходит встреча гласных, и после А, Е, У пишется суффикс Я а после О – суффикс И (строить, беспокоить)"_. **Так в ПАС именно так и написано!!!** А о том, что такие сочетания  встречаются только в глаголах с усекаемой основой, сказано в скобках.  По-моему, как раз этот-то пункт правил в ПАС сформулирован очень понятно.

Comment: Ну да, всё понятно, только  ребенок ничего не понял. Стык гласных не увидел, зато стал анализировать основу на предмет усекаемости (как раз ту, которая в скобках указана). Вообще понятие об усекаемости основы  - вещь полезная, но только не в этой теме. Я бы не рекомендовала школьникам читать то, что написано в § 76, для практического применения эти сведения, с моей точки зрения,  непригодны.

Answer (score 0):

Я своим ученикам давала для заучивания:

КлеИть,вялИть,строИть,жалИть,

МетИть, молвИть и манИть,

БеспокоИться, осилИть,

ЕздИть,бросИть, победИть -

Их писать в начальной форме

Надо только через -ИТЬ.

ВеЯть, блеЯть,чуЯть, лаЯть,

РеЯть, таЯть,сеЯть,чаЯть,

И надеЯться, лелеЯть,

КашлЯть,каЯться, стоЯть -

Их писать в начальной форме

Надо только через -ЯТЬ.

В глаголах с приставками обез/обес суффикс Е пишем, если он непереходный(сам делает): обессилеть, обездометь, обеззубеть самому; суффикс И - если переходный (кого-то, что-то) обессилить врага, обеззаразить рану.

Запомнить: обезвредить, обезглавить, обессмертить, обезобразить,

Но: обеспамятеть, обезголосеть, обеззубеть.

**А сомневаетесь - смотрите в словарь.**

Comment: Я не думаю, что такая подача материала удачна. Стихи-запоминалки, заучивание наизусть. словарь - всё это даже для младшей школы не лучший вариант. Такая система лишает учащихся знаний и не развивает интерес к языку. Надо ЧЕСТНО рассказывать детям, что такое глагольный суффикс и почему смысловую морфему сложно выбрать по ее значению. Тем не менее это значение присутствует во многих глаголах, и это интересно видеть.  Проблема - это то, что притягивает и развивает ум,  а запоминалки  и неоправданная зубрежка пользы не принесут.